# Math in javascript doesnt work the way i expected

Tags: javascript, math, logic, jshint

Im trying to use this equation to make a progress bar but when ever i try to divide a number with a percent it just gives me a error.

---

The equation:

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
let progress = (this.assetsComplete*100%)/((this.assets.length - this.exceptionLength)*40);
```

---

The only problem is when i do the division it gives an error is there a way to fix it?

i have tried adding extra parentheses but that didn't work.

Comment: you may have a look to the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder), which is different from using the same symbol for percent calculations.

Comment: Multiplying by 100%, even if there were such syntax, is the same as multiplying by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take it without some percent calculation.

```
let progress = this.assetsComplete * 40 / (this.assets.length - this.exceptionLength);
```

The [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) returns a rest of a dvision of a number by another number.